# ImageIO.read() memory consumption

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks, javax.imageio

I´m currently trying to figure out where my application has a memory leak. So, I wrote a small test program since my memory leaks seem to be related to the ImageIO.read() method. My test application consists of a simple JFrame with a JButton, which starts the following Action:

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        File folder = new File("C:\\Pictures");
        ArrayList<File> files = new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(folder.listFiles()));
        try
        {
            for (File file : files)
                ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch (Exception a)
        {
            a.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Although I do NOT save the return value, that is the image, of ImageIO.read, my application has a huge memory allocation (~800 MB). For test reasons, the folder C:\Pictures contains ~23k pictures with a total size of 25GB.

Why does ImageIO.read() reserves that much memory, even after returning and NOT saving the image anywhere else?

Comment: It could still be apparent due to garbage collector not coming by and picking up derefrenced objects yet. Try invoking System.gc() afterwards and see where your memory is. EDIT: Manually invoking gsrbage collector results in a "stop the world" effect. All threads will be haulted until the garbage collector has finished. I suggest finding better methods for garbage collecting over time

Comment: @VinceErnigh Manually invoking GC does not 'stop the world' and may in fact do nothing at all. See the Javadoc, which you are here contradicting.

Comment: As a rule of thumb: If your application does **not** eventually throw an `OutOfMemoryError`, then you do **not** have a memory leak. (Of course, it may be a "small" leak, so that this error would only appear after days of weeks of running, but) the key point is that the size that is reported, for example, by the Windows Task Manager or so, does hardly say anything about how much memory is actually *required* or "actively used" - it only says (roughly: ) how much memory is "reserved by the JVM for potential use".

Comment: @EJP STW occurs no matter what gc algorithm you use, and when you call System.gc(), it will cause a STW effect if objects are recycled and memory is freed. Yes, sometimes System.gc() won't do anything, but it's the easiest way of manually invoking the GC, without using some kind of memory analyzer that might have the option. I commented to bring the reason to his attention, and I put the disclaimer so the OP realized it wasn't an easy fix for every situation.

Comment: @VinceErnigh Citation please. I haven't experienced a garbage-collection 'stop he world' in Java since about 1997.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't 'reserve that much memory'. It can't. All that seems to have happened here is that it took about 800 image loads before GC kicked in.

Why are you loading 23k images? It seems a strange thing to do. Where are you going to display them? Do you have an extra-large screen?

Comment: you´re right! If I decrease heap size, it "reserves" less memory. It always goes to the maximum bound but it does not exceed it and throws an exception. So, I think your´re right with your answer! Thanks :)